# Where is HTML code for admin page: Product -> General

Tags: admin, template

Regarding the following admin page:
`Catalog -> Manage Products -> Click on any product -> General`

Where is the HTML code located for this page?

I have turned on template paths hints for admin, but after following up a few templates, I couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: If my answer isn't the right file, and if you are looking for a specific element on the page, clarifying that might help us locate the template file you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, magento is not using any phtml template for generating the content for `General` tab. The html part which generates while click on this tab is actually hard coded inside magento.

In order to explain my point, please have a look on the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs::_prepareLayout()` which is a part of the core module `Mage_Adminhtml`. In short, this method is used to construct the tabs section which you will see in product edit page(admin side).

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    ......

        foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
            $attributes = $product->getAttributes($group->getId(), true);

            $this->addTab('group_'.$group->getId(), array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($group->getAttributeGroupName()),
                'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->getAttributeTabBlock(),
                    'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($group)
                        ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                        ->toHtml()),
            ));
        }
        .....
}
```

** *For the purpose of explanation, showed only relevant code.*

Here you can see a `foreach` loop which is looping through `Attribute Group Collection`(`$groupCollection`). For an example `General`, `Price`, `Meta Information`, `Images` etc are attribute groups. Inside the loop, you can see that generation of tabs which are corresponds to these attribute groups are occuring thorugh `$this->addTab()`.ie

```
$this->addTab('group_'.$group->getId(), array(
       'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($group->getAttributeGroupName()),
       'content'   => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->getAttributeTabBlock(),
                        'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($group)
                            ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                            ->toHtml()),
));
```

`addTab` is used to generate tabs and its content. `label` stands for text that will appear in the tab. For an example, for general tab, label will be `General`. `content` section stands for what should show when that tab get selected. This means `addTab`  function allows to add multiple tabs and we can also set what should show inside the tab. This is highly recommended since using the same method we can generate and show dynamic contents in and edit page. (Actually the full admin section is made up of this concept. We are using some general block classes in order to show dynamic contents.).

Now let us have a look on `content` section in more depth. You can see that, it dynamically adds a new block to the layout, then convert it into html codes using `toHtml()`. For example, in case of `General` tab, the code will look like

```
'content' => $this->_translateHtml(
                 $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                     'adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_attributes',                     
                     'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes'
                 )->setGroup($group)
                 ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                            ->toHtml())
```

Here what happens here is, it is creating a block instance of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes` and set it with a group and a set of attributes which come under that particular group and then finally convert that block into html codes using `toHtml()`. That means for every attribute group sections, it uses same block type (but different instance). The difference comes through by setting group and group attributes. So here again magento uses a general layout and use it dynamically for different tabs.

> So in effect, you can't find a phtml file corresponding to a tab in
>   the case of `Attribute Groups` which are showing in the catalog
>   product edit page (admin side.). The content is generating is hard
>   coded within magento.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all this information. I followed up all the files/classes and found just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml` which indicates it is the template for `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit`.

Comment: Thanks but I had already looked in that file with no luck. In regards to your other comment, I was actually after any HTML input tag on the General page. Solved now though!